# Charts for $\mathbb S^1$ exercise.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

So here is the following exercise:

For $\theta \in R$ we define $U_{\theta}:=\mathbb{S}^1 \setminus\{\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)\}\subset \mathbb S^1$ and

$$\varphi_{\theta}:U_{\theta} \rightarrow (\theta,\theta+2\pi)\subset \mathbb R,  (\cos(\rho),\sin(\rho))\mapsto \rho$$

(i) Explain why this is well defined and show that $(U_{\theta}, \varphi_{\theta})_{\theta \in R}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ atlas for $\mathbb S^1$.

(ii) Show that

$$\{(x_0,x_1)\in \mathbb S_1 | x_1>0 \}\rightarrow \mathbb R, (x_0, x_1) \mapsto \dfrac{x_0}{x_1}$$ is another chart for $\mathbb S^1$ and decide whether it is in the $C^{\infty}$ structure defined by the atlas $(U_\theta, \varphi_\theta)_{\theta \in R}$.

1. I am not really asking for the solution of this problem, I just want someone to explain what am I supposed to show in part (ii) exactly. What does it mean to "be in the structure of the atlas"? Is it just to show that some transition functions are smooth?
2. Also, for part i) I am struggling to give a precise formal explicit argument that the maps $\varphi_{\theta}$ are continuous, even though it is quite clear how they work.
   Thank you.